# Powers of convergent sequence

Tags: real-analysis

Given a sequence of real numbers $\left\{ r_{\alpha} \right\}_{\alpha}$ converging to $1$, does $\left\{r_{\alpha}^{\alpha}\right\}_{\alpha}$ converge to $1$ as well?

Comment: Not any more than a sequence $\{s_\alpha\}_{\alpha\in\Bbb N}$ such that $s_\alpha\to 0$ satisfies $\alpha s_\alpha\to 0$.

Comment: If $x_\alpha=\alpha^{1/\alpha}$, then $x_\alpha\to1$ but $x_\alpha^{\alpha}=\alpha$ doesn't.